# sql query getting ID wise balance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a following SQL Query:(**Oracle 10**)

```
SELECT
     A.ID,
     SUM(A.AMT_CR) - SUM(A.AMT_DR) AS balAmt,
     P.NAME
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 P
WHERE P.ID BETWEEN 'C0100' AND 'C0200'
    AND P.ID = A.ID
    AND A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013'
GROUP BY A.ID, P.NAME
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Above query executes nicely, but this query has a condition `AND A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013'`. This condition is for getting the `balAmt` before the `TRANS_DATE`. But the issue with this query is that it only gets the `IDs` with respect to `AND A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013'` condition. If a `ID` doesn't have `TRANS_DATE` less than `'01-FEB-2013'` then it doesn't show the record for that `ID`.

So I want to get All `IDs` from database. But I want to get `balAmt` with respect to `AND A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013'` condition..

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
     A.ID,
     SUM(case when A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013' 
         then nvl(A.AMT_CR,0) - nvl(A.AMT_DR,0)
         else 0
         end) AS balAmt,
     P.NAME
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 P
WHERE P.ID BETWEEN 'C0100' AND 'C0200'
    AND P.ID = A.ID
GROUP BY A.ID, P.NAME
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Q.ID, W.balmt, W.NAME
FROM TABLE1 Q
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
     A.ID,
     SUM(A.AMT_CR) - SUM(A.AMT_DR) AS balAmt,
     P.NAME
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 P
WHERE P.ID BETWEEN 'C0100' AND 'C0200'
    AND P.ID = A.ID
    AND A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013'
GROUP BY A.ID, P.NAME
) W
ON Q.ID = W.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT
     A.ID,
     SUM(A.AMT_CR) - SUM(A.AMT_DR) AS balAmt,
     P.NAME
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 P ON P.ID = A.ID
                   AND A.TRANS_DATE < '01-FEB-2013'
                   AND P.ID BETWEEN 'C0100' AND 'C0200'
GROUP BY A.ID, P.NAME
ORDER BY A.ID
```